# Explanations in Consistent OWL Ontologies

Tags: java, intellij-idea, owl, owl-api, owlready

I want to programmatically get explanations for inferred axioms in **consistent** ontologies, in a similar manner that one can do in the Protégé UI. I cannot find any straightforward way. I have found the [owlexplanation repo](https://github.com/matthewhorridge/owlexplanation), but I cannot for the life of me solve the dependency issues to set up the `owlexplanation` environment. I have also browsed the [javadoc](https://owlcs.github.io/owlapi/apidocs_5/index.html) of owlapi regarding explanations (to avoid the other repo altogether), but I don't see anything useful beyond what I can already see browsing the Java source code.

I have thought of simply negating the inferred axiom, to get explanations through inconsistencies, but I would prefer something cleaner, and I am not sure this approach is correct anyway.

Other (possibly) useful context:

- I had used some Java years ago, but I now primarily use Python (I try to use OWL API with JPype and OWL in general with Owlready2).
- I am using HermiT reasoner (again through JPype) (according to build.xml file, <s>latest stable</s> version 1.3.8).
- I have managed to get explanations for unsatisfiability and inconsistency in my setup, without `owlexplanation`, following [this](https://github.com/phillord/hermit-reasoner/blob/master/examples/org/semanticweb/HermiT/examples/Explanations.java) example from the  HermiT source code.
- I fell in the rabbit hole wanting to make a usable `.jar` file for `owlexplanation`, in order to add it in my JPype classpath. My plan went sideways when I couldn't get the Java project to build in the first place.
- I am using Intellij IDE.

I would appreciate any insight or tips.

**UPDATE Jan 6, 2022:**

I decided to try once more with the `owlexplanation` code with a clean head so here is where I am at:

- Downloaded the source code from github and extracted the zip.
- Started IntelliJ and instead from "Creating a project from Existing sources", I clicked "Open" and selected the extracted directory.
- I built the project and it did successfully.
- From Maven tools, I run clean, validate, compile and test succesfully.
- If I run "package" Maven action, it throws as error that "The environment variable JAVA_HOME is not correctly set". The thing is that if I go File>Project Structure, I see that SDK is set to 11, it's not empty.
- Additionally, from the `pom.xml` file I get these problems:

  - `Plugin 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-gpg-plugin:1.5' not found`
  - `Plugin 'org.sonatype.plugins:nexus-staging-maven-plugin:1.6.6' not found`

**UPDATE Jan 8, 2022**: *(Trying @Ignazio's answer)*

I created a new IntelliJ project, and added the Maven dependencies @Ignazio mentioned (plus some others like `slf4j` etc) and I got a working example (I think). Moving to my main project (using JPype), I had to manually download some .jars to include in the classpath (as maven can't be used here). These are the ones downloaded so far:

```
caffeine-3.0.5.jar         hppcrt-0.7.5.jar    org.semanticweb.hermit-1.4.5.519.jar  slf4j-api-1.7.32.jar
commons-rdf-api-0.5.0.jar  javax.inject-1.jar  owlapi-distribution-5.1.9.jar         slf4j-nop-1.7.32.jar
google-collect-1.0.jar     owlexplanation-5.0.0.jar
```

Next, a `NullPointerException` is thrown when trying to use `loadOntologyFromOntologyDocument()`. I have tried re-downloading the jars as proposed [here](https://github.com/owlcs/owlapi/issues/807#issuecomment-442095448), but the Exception remains. Could it be that some .jar is missing? I downloaded them based on the thrown `NoClassDefFoundError` that would occur.

This occurs with a common `pizza.owl` file that it is otherwise fully working.

**EDIT**: I used `mvn dependency:copy-dependencies -DoutputDirectory=OUTPUT_DIR` to get the dependencies and by using OUTPUT_DIR as the classpath, the `NullPointerException` is gone, so it seems I was indeed missing some .jar file.

For the record, I then got other issues (`gen.getExplanations()` was throwing a `NoSuchMethodError` error), but I have no more time for debugging this. I will ditch JPype, however convenient it is, and simply call Java from Python with `subprocess`. These are (I guess) Jpype problems, so I am accepting Ignazio's answer as it solved my Java/OWL API/owlexplanation side of things.

Comment: not sure if I understand, because you first said "I cannot for the life of me solve the dependency issues to set up the environment" and then you said " have managed to get explanations for unsatisfiability and inconsistency in my setup." - that is confusing. Are you able to use the API or not? If not, what kind of exception to you get?

Comment: Note, I tried it in a local Java project with the current Github code built and installed via Maven, then used as the dependency - works as expected for an arbitrary axiom provided as entailment.

Comment: Which HermiT version? Some older releases include OWLAPI 3 classes and that creates plenty of conflicts.

Comment: Sorry for the missing info, I edited my answer. @Ignazio HermiT version must be 1.3.8 downloaded [here](http://www.hermit-reasoner.com/download.html). @UninformedUser I have managed to use the OWL API through HermiT but not for all I want. I can't solve the dependencies for the `owlexplanation` project. Is it the `owlexplanation` code you used successfully?

Comment: That HermiT version includes old OWLAPI classes, meaning it would be hard to make it work with the owlexplanation project

Comment: Thanks for the tip @Ignazio. This is a point of failure I hadn't reached yet. I wasn't even aware of this, it seems www.hermit-reasoner.com isn't up to date. What version would you suggest me use, supposing I manage to make `owlexplanation` run? I found [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sourceforge.owlapi/org.semanticweb.hermit) version 1.4.5. This is the latest, I guess.

Comment: NullPointerException at that point is most likely a file in the wrong place. Always add the code and a stack trace when asking about the reason for an exception, though, otherwise we're just guessing.

Comment: I "solved" the NullPointer one, and finally decided to use a more native Java approach based on your insight. I have updated my post accordingly. Thanks for your help @Ignazio, you are awesome ;)

Comment: Now that you have a working solution, it would be nice to publish it, e.g. as a github project. I think it would be a good thing to add to the list https://github.com/pysemtec/semantic-python-overview as it (probably) demonstrates how solve a nontrivial semantic problem (getting explanations for a consistent ontology) by calling java code from python.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @cknoll, duly noted! As I still work on my projects now, I can certainly look into this prospect in the next months. I'd love to give back to the community a working package, that's for sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not just using the projects but actually building them from scratch, which requires more setup than using the published artifacts.

Shortcut that uses Maven available jars (via Maven Central, although other public repositories should do just as well)

Java code:

```
    import java.io.File;
    import java.util.Set;
    import java.util.function.Supplier;
    
    import org.junit.Test;
    import org.semanticweb.HermiT.ReasonerFactory;
    import org.semanticweb.owl.explanation.api.Explanation;
    import org.semanticweb.owl.explanation.api.ExplanationGenerator;
    import org.semanticweb.owl.explanation.api.ExplanationGeneratorFactory;
    import org.semanticweb.owl.explanation.api.ExplanationProgressMonitor;
    import org.semanticweb.owl.explanation.impl.blackbox.Configuration;
    import org.semanticweb.owl.explanation.impl.blackbox.DivideAndConquerContractionStrategy;
    import org.semanticweb.owl.explanation.impl.blackbox.EntailmentCheckerFactory;
    import org.semanticweb.owl.explanation.impl.blackbox.InitialEntailmentCheckStrategy;
    import org.semanticweb.owl.explanation.impl.blackbox.StructuralTypePriorityExpansionStrategy;
    import org.semanticweb.owl.explanation.impl.blackbox.checker.BlackBoxExplanationGeneratorFactory;
    import org.semanticweb.owl.explanation.impl.blackbox.checker.SatisfiabilityEntailmentCheckerFactory;
    import org.semanticweb.owlapi.apibinding.OWLManager;
    import org.semanticweb.owlapi.model.OWLAxiom;
    import org.semanticweb.owlapi.model.OWLOntology;
    import org.semanticweb.owlapi.model.OWLOntologyManager;
    import org.semanticweb.owlapi.reasoner.OWLReasonerFactory;
    
    public class CheckOntology {
    
        @Test
        public void should() throws Exception {
    
            OWLOntologyManager m = OWLManager.createOWLOntologyManager();
            OWLOntology o = m.loadOntologyFromOntologyDocument(new File("pizza.owl"));
    
            OWLReasonerFactory rf = new ReasonerFactory(); // Get hold of a reasoner factory
    
            // Create the explanation generator factory which uses reasoners provided by the specified
            // reasoner factory
    
            ExplanationGeneratorFactory<OWLAxiom> genFac =
                createExplanationGeneratorFactory(rf, null, OWLManager::createOWLOntologyManager);
    
            // Now create the actual explanation generator for our ontology
            ExplanationGenerator<OWLAxiom> gen = genFac.createExplanationGenerator(o);
    
    
            // Ask for explanations for some entailment
            // Get a reference to the axiom that represents the entailment that we want explanation for
            
            // this will just run the explanations for all axioms
            o.logicalAxioms().forEach(e -> explain(e, gen));
        }
    
        void explain(OWLAxiom entailment, ExplanationGenerator<OWLAxiom> gen) {
            // Get our explanations. Ask for a maximum of 5.
            try {
                Set<Explanation<OWLAxiom>> expl = gen.getExplanations(entailment, 5);
                System.out.println("CheckOntology.explain() " + entailment);
                expl.forEach(System.out::println);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    // this method replicates code existing in the owlexplanation project; it's needed because the factories in owlexplanation do not set InitialEntailmentCheckStrategy correctly
        public static ExplanationGeneratorFactory<OWLAxiom> createExplanationGeneratorFactory(
            OWLReasonerFactory reasonerFactory, ExplanationProgressMonitor<OWLAxiom> progressMonitor,
            Supplier<OWLOntologyManager> m) {
            EntailmentCheckerFactory<OWLAxiom> checker =
                new SatisfiabilityEntailmentCheckerFactory(reasonerFactory, m);
            Configuration<OWLAxiom> config = new Configuration<>(checker,
                new StructuralTypePriorityExpansionStrategy<OWLAxiom>(
                    InitialEntailmentCheckStrategy.PERFORM, m),
                new DivideAndConquerContractionStrategy<OWLAxiom>(), progressMonitor, m);
            return new BlackBoxExplanationGeneratorFactory<>(config);
        }
    }
```

Maven configuration:

4.0.0
blah
blah
0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
blah


junit
junit
4.12


net.sourceforge.owlapi
org.semanticweb.hermit
1.4.5.519


net.sourceforge.owlapi
owlexplanation
5.0.0

HermiT is available on Maven Central via release builds I've made - the patch version refers to the OWLAPI version it was built with. Here 1.4.5.519 means HermiT was built with OWLAPI 5.1.9. owlexplanation 5.0.0 was built with OWLAPI 5, so it's the same major OWLAPI version for the project.

This code sample doesn't do a lot because it just looks for explanations of asserted axioms. Often the explanation is just the axiom itself, as it's asserted. Varying the chosen axiom, or using axioms not asserted in the ontology, should give you the explanations you are after.

Comment: As for making a jar out of the whole, it should be possible but the number of dependencies to include is fairly large.

Comment: Thanks @Ignazio, your input has helped me a lot! If you can give me a little more of your time, I updated my post above with some more details. Do you maybe have any thoughts? I appreciate your help.